# saucelabs - maximize screen resolution

Tags: browser, phpunit, saucelabs

I am running automated test cases using phpunit. I will have to maximize the screen first for some of the elements to be visible. I have in my code in the setup() function:

```
function setUp() {
    $session = $this->prepareSession();
    $session->currentWindow()->maximize();
}
```

But when i run it in saucelabs, i dont see that this command works (the browser does not maximize) and the test cases fail with "Element not found" error. How do I open the screen with max resolution using phpunit in saucelabs?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be specified in the DesiredCapabilities("screen-resolution","1280x1024") or so.You might also want to checkout https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/#/